# On the position of ‘jedoch’ in a clause

Tags: grammar, word-order, adverb

The following example sentence is quoted from Duden:

> er fand den Ausgang der Sache bedauerlich, entmutigen jedoch ließ er sich nicht;

The word *jedoch* is labelled as an adverb in the dictionary; hence in the 2nd clause there are two words before the finite verb *ließ* which then occupies the 3rd position in the clause; does this violate the *verb-second* rule? How can we reconcile them?

Comment: Keine Ahnung, wieso die Beispiele beim Duden mit Kleinbuchstaben beginnen - im Englischen begannen, als ich es lernte, Sätze jedoch groß.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placement of *jedoch* in your example is indeed a little bit weird, as long as it is not enclosed in a pair of commas marking it an insertion into the sentence (as which I automatically read it, pauses included).

It would be no real problem (see your previous questions) if *jedoch* had been in first — or actually zeroth — position in that sentence. And it would also not be a problem if *jedoch* occupied a later position after the verb:

> […] entmutigen ließ er sich jedoch nicht.

Whatever the actual case is, while it *is* a violation of basic rules it is still okay if used for emphatic (or poetic) reasons. So I think you should just mentally mark it as an exception and move on.